# _CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, date, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to add a Date (yyyy/mm/dd) to Firebase and when converting the `_selectedDate` to a yMd format I am getting this error somnewhere else in my code `_CastError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast)`

Declare variable:

```
String _selectedDate = DateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd").format(DateTime.now()).toString();
```

The place where you can enter the date:

```
MyInputField(
title: "Date",
hint: DateFormat.yMd().format(_selectedDate))
```

Comment: Not really a good idea to store a date as a string on a database, means processing it is pretty messy. Much better to use a millisecondssinceepoch integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess hint requires `String` and already you converted `DateTime.now()` to String. So, you may not be allowed to call `format` for `_selectedDate`.

```
MyInputField(
title: "Date",
hint: _selectedDate)
```

or in assignment

```
DateTime _selectedTime = DateTime.now();
```

You are supposed to user either a way, not both.